# Finding total "wait" time for concurrently running transactions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I need to evaluate several million lines of performance logging for a manufacturing execution system.  I need to group the data by date, class and name with finding the total "wait time" of numerous concurrently running transactions.  The data comes in looking similar to what is in this dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd

    d = {'START_DATE': ['2021-08-07 19:11:40', '2021-08-07 19:11:40', '2021-08-07 19:11:40',
                   '2021-08-07 19:20:40', '2021-08-07 19:20:40', '2021-08-07 19:20:40',
                   '2021-08-07 19:21:40', '2021-08-07 19:21:40', '2021-08-07 19:21:40',
                   '2021-08-10 19:20:40', '2021-08-10 19:20:40', '2021-08-10 19:20:40',
                   '2021-08-10 19:21:40', '2021-08-10 19:21:40', '2021-08-10 19:21:40'
                   ],
    
        'ELAPSED_TIME': ['00:00:00.465', '00:00:01.000', '00:00:00.165',
                         '00:00:00.100', '00:00:00.200', '00:03:00.000',
                         '00:05:00.000', '00:00:00.200', '00:00:03.000',
                         '00:00:00.100', '00:00:00.200', '00:03:00.000',
                         '00:05:00.000', '00:00:00.200', '00:00:03.000'
                         ],
    
        'TRANSACTION': ['a', 'b', 'c',
                        'a', 'd', 'c',
                        'e', 'a', 'b',
                        'a', 'd', 'c',
                        'e', 'a', 'b'
                        ],
    
        'USER': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob',
                 'Biff', 'Biff', 'Biff',
                 'Biff', 'Biff', 'Biff',
                 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob',
                 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob'
                 ],
    
        'CLASS':  ['AA', 'AA', 'AA',
                   'BB', 'BB', 'BB',
                   'BB', 'BB', 'BB',
                   'AA', 'AA', 'AA',
                   'AA', 'AA', 'AA'
                   ]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

See how the transaction times will start at the same time and run concurrent with each other, but will be "done" at different times.  E.g. Bob's first set of transactions (rows 0-2) all take a different amount of time, but when I group by DATE, CLASS, and USER--I want to show the total wait time to be 1000ms (based on the second line's wait time).

On 08/07/2021, Biff has two sets of transactions starting at different times, but they will still overlap into one wait time--6000ms.

Expected output would look something like:

```
DATE           CLASS     USER     Wait
2021-08-07     AA        Bob      1000
2021-08-07     BB        Biff     360000
2021-08-10     AA        Bob      360000
```

Like I mentioned the actual data has several millions lines of transactions--I am looking for help in finding something better (and hopefully faster than what I have/found):

```
def getSecs1(grp):
    return pd.DatetimeIndex([]).union_many([ pd.date_range(
        row.START_DATE, row.END_DATE, freq='25ms', closed='left')
            for _, row in grp.iterrows() ]).size
```

I add an END_DATE column by adding the milliseconds to the START_DATE.  I have to do it with chunks of 25ms otherwise it would take wwaayy too long to do.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

###Edit
Change the overlap to minutes

Comment: if the start and end are in different days do you allocate portions to each day?

Comment: That would be best yes--so whatever burned into the next day would count for that day--but to be honest, which ever way is easier and quicker.

Comment: I'm not sure your data is consistent with your expected results.  For example Biff with start date 2021-08-07 19:20:40 and duration 00:00:03.000 will end at 2021-08-07 19:20:43.  For start date 2021-08-07 19:21:40 and duration 00:00:05.000 the end point will be 2021-08-07 19:21:45 - these intervals do not overlap and their total is not 6000ms.

Comment: My bad--you are right.  In my mind I was thinking minutes but wrote seconds.  I will change it.

Comment: Ok--changed to minutes for the "overlap" on time and then did some quick millisecond math.  Trying to show how some sets of transaction will overlap each other--but should still be part of the same cumulative wait time.

Comment: Now can you explain me why 360000 and not 180000, please?

Comment: First set kicks off at 2021-08-07 19:20:40 (longest transaction is 3 minutes), second set kicks off at 2021-08-07 19:21:40 (one minute later with a longest transaction of 5 minutes).  This would be a total of 6 minutes.  1000 x 60 x 6 = 360000ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a package called [`staircase`](https://staircase.dev) which is built on pandas and numpy for working with (mathematical) step functions.  You can think of an interval as being a step function which goes from value 0 to 1 at the start of an interval and 1 to 0 at the end of an interval.

**additional setup**

convert `START_DATE` and `ELAPSED_TIME` to appropriate `pandas` time objects

```
df["START_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["START_DATE"])
df["ELAPSED_TIME"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["ELAPSED_TIME"])
```

define daily bins

```
dates = pd.period_range("2021-08-07", "2021-08-10")
```

**solution**

Define a function which takes a dataframe, makes a step function from start and end times (calculated as start + duration), sets non-zero values to 1, slices the step function with the bins, and integrates.

```
import staircase as sc

def calc_dates_for_user(df_):
    return (
        sc.Stairs(  # creating step function
             start=df_["START_DATE"],
             end=df_["START_DATE"] + df_["ELAPSED_TIME"],
        )
        .make_boolean()  # where two intervals overlap the value of the step function will be 2.  This sets all non-zero values to 1 (effectively creating a union of intervals).
        .slice(dates)  # analogous to groupby
        .integral()/pd.Timedelta("1s")  # for each slice integrate (which will equal the length of the interval) and divide by seconds
    )
```

When we groupby `USER` and `CLASS` and apply this function we get a dataframe, indexed by these variables, with a column index corresponding to intervals in the period range

```
USER CLASS   [2021-08-07, 2021-08-08)  [2021-08-08, 2021-08-09)  [2021-08-09, 2021-08-10)    [2021-08-10, 2021-08-11)                                              
Biff BB                      360000.0                        0.0                        0.0                       0.0 
Bob  AA                        1000.0                        0.0                        0.0                  360000.0
```

We'll clean it up like so

```
result = (
    df.groupby(["USER", "CLASS"])  
    .apply(calc_dates_for_user)
    .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name="DATE", value_name="WAIT")  # melt column index into a single column of daily intervals
    .query("WAIT != 0")  # filter out days where no time recorded
    .reset_index() # move USER and CLASS from index to columns
)
```

`result` then looks like this

```
   USER CLASS                      DATE      WAIT
0  Biff    BB  [2021-08-07, 2021-08-08)  360000.0
1   Bob    AA  [2021-08-07, 2021-08-08)    1000.0
2   Bob    AA  [2021-08-10, 2021-08-11)  360000.0
```

To get your expected result you can replace the DATE column with the timestamps relating to day-start with

```
result["DATE"] = pd.IntervalIndex(result["DATE"]).left
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Ok--I don't where to begin.  I just ran this on around 6.5 million lines and you just saved me HOURS!  Thank you!